# Django pass model name as parameter to decorator

Tags: django, decorator

I have the following decorator in my app which checks if the current user has created any Location objects and redirects them to another url if they have not.

```
def location_required(f):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        locations = Location.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        if locations.count() == 0:
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
    wrap.__doc__=f.__doc__
    wrap.__name__=f.__name__
    return wrap
```

I would like to have similar functionality for a number of other models.  Rather than creating several decorators, I would like to be able to just pass the model name as a parameter (and probably the url to redirect to as well).

Is this possible and what changes do I need to make?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely possible. It might end up looking something like the following (untested) code:

```
def object_required(model_class, redirect_url):
    def location_required(f):
        def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
            locations = model_class.objects.filter(user=request.user)
            if locations.count() == 0:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
            return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
        wrap.__doc__=f.__doc__
        wrap.__name__=f.__name__
        return wrap
    return location_required
```

All I've done here is add another layer of wrapping. Your original decorator customized the function f that was passed in. My outer layer customizes your decorator. You would use it in the same way:

```
@object_required(Location, '/')
def my_view_func(request)
    #your view code
```

Answer (score 2):

Gareth's approach of wrapping your existing decorator in another function which handles the model class and redirect url is correct. I suggest the following small changes:

- Use `exists()` instead of comparing `count()` to zero
- Use `django.utils.functional.wraps` to update the wrap function instead of setting `__name__` and `__doc__` manually.
- The `locations` variable in the wrap function is misnamed, now that it could be a any model instance.

This gives:

```
from django.utils.functional import wraps

def object_required(model_class, redirect_url="/"):
    # model_class and redirect_url are available to all inner functions
    def decorator(f):
        # this is called with f, the function being decorated
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            # this is called each time the real function is executed
            instances = model_class.objects.filter(user=request.user)
            if not instances.exists():
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
            return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return wraps(f)(wrapper)
    return decorator
```

In the view:

```
@object_required(Location, "/")
def my_view_function(request):
    # your view code
```

Comment: Thanks.  Where would be the best place to put this in terms of re-use throughout a project?  Would a separate app just for decorator functions be overkill?

Comment: Perhaps create a `utils` app, and put the decorator in `utils.decorators`.